# First Empty cell in row

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell, rows

I am copying a range into the next empty cell of a different workbook. the following code;

```
Public Sub InvoicedInstallments()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim fname As String
Dim mt As String, yr As String
mt = MonthBox.Value
yr = YearBox.Value
fname = yr & mt & "DB" & ".xlsx"
Set rng1 = Workbooks("201209TB.xlsx").Worksheets("excel").Range("E348")
Set rng2 = Workbooks("201209TB.xlsx").Worksheets("excel").Range("E295")
Set rng3 = Workbooks(fname).Worksheets("UK monthly dashboard").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Select

rng3.Value = (rng1.Value + rng2.Value)
rng3.Value = rng3.Value * -1
rng3.Value = Round(rng3.Value / 1000, 0)

End Sub
```

Has had the line

```
Set rng3 = Workbooks(fname).Worksheets("UK monthly dashboard").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Select
```

changed to

```
Set rng3 = Workbooks(fname).Worksheets("UK monthly dashboard").Range("AA49").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
```

this will now put the data into the next empty cell (which is what I wanted) but it does not then put information into the next empty cell if you run the code again.

I imagine it is just something simple but I can't spot it

It is copying into merged cells which I suspect holds a lot of issues
(see below comments for confirmation of this)

Comment: the range is the sum of cell E348 + E295 in 201209TB and it goes into the next blank cell of row 49

Comment: Range("AA49") -> this is why, you start always at the same position

Comment: So how would I change that to be the next blank cell in the row?

Comment: Ok so I have it sorted and pasting into the next empty cell for a row  

    Set rng2 = Workbooks(fname).Worksheets("UK monthly dashboard").Cells(55, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)  

which works fine but because of the merged cell this copies the range into the next single cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing, your problem will be in this line:

```
rng3.Value = Round(rng3.Value / 1000, 0)
```

but the error is thrown here

```
Set rng3 = Workbooks(fname).Worksheets("UK monthly dashboard").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Select
```

it is because of the `select`.

`Select`, selects, it does not return you a range object.

use this instead

```
Set rng3 = Workbooks(fname).Worksheets("UK monthly dashboard").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight)
```

However, I am not sure, if this is what you want, because you might just say

```
Set rng3 = Workbooks(fname).Worksheets("UK monthly dashboard").Range("IV1")
```

because this is what you get - at least, if you are working only with `.xlsx`

Comment: This has stopped the error but the data is not appearing on the worksheet

Comment: I'm probably not communicating very well, what I have is a row full of data for each month of 2012, when the code is run I want it to look for the next blank cell (which would be the next month) and put the data in there. This would be fine if the cell was just the same each month but it will change constantly

Comment: @JamesDev - please see my edit, use the debugger - I have a strong feeling, that you don't now what exactly you are reffereing/using. State what you want to achieve, otherwise it is hard to guess your goal ;)

Comment: @JamesDev - ok, I did solve your only question in your initial post, however, as I suspected, you are dealing with a whole task of merging data of your two files into the monthly dashboard, well, you will learn a lot by solving this, and SO and SU will provide you a lot of similar examples of this task - just apply them to your situation.

Comment: You solved the error which is appreciated greatly, still no further with the overall problem however

Comment: Fixed to a degree, see end of question for line of code which posts in the next cell but when run a second time does not post in further cells.