# Copied range searches for next empty cell in a row but skips merged cells

Tags: vba, excel, merge, excel-2007, range

I've seen a lot of people talking about this problem but more from a point of view of copying merged cells into single cells. I have a procedure that gets a range from a workbook, opens the second workbook and attempts to paste it into the next blank cell in the specified row;

```
Public Sub BankBalances()
Dim fname As String
Dim fname2 As String
Dim mt As String, yr As String
'get the selected month
mt = MonthBox.Value
'get the selected year
yr = YearBox.Value
'set the file path to the selected year, month and the saving format
fname = yr & mt & "DB" & ".xlsx"
'set the file path to the selected year, month to open the trial balance sheet
fname2 = yr & mt & "TB" & ".xlsx"
'get the ranges
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Workbooks(fname2).Worksheets("excel").Range("I100")
'check for the next empty cell in row 55
Set rng2 = Workbooks(fname).Worksheets("UK monthly dashboard").Cells(55, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
'set the new range to hold the data from the original range
rng2.Value = rng1.Value
'set the result to format according to the other information in the workbook
rng2.Value = Round(rng1.Value / 1000, 0)

End Sub
```

The above code will paste the data in the next blank cell in the row that is not merged. I need it to be able to paste into the merged cells.

What I want to know is if there is a way using VBA to put the data into the merged cell or if I will need to do a separate procedure to check for merged cells, unmerge them and then merge them once the data has copied across.

If that is the way, would I be able to do that in a similar way to checking for the next empty cell, then check if it's merged, then carry out the unmerge and merge again.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028201/first-empty-cell-in-row

Comment: It's similar but as that was an issue with just getting the ranges to copy it's not a duplicate. Secondly that is my question as well and thirdly it's only been kept open to see if anyone comes up with anything but I am happy for that one to be closed

Comment: So if you copy say Cells A1:A5 and you have D1:D5 merged then do you want the contents of A1:A5 "inside" the merged cell?

Comment: If I understand what you are saying then yes, but if I may alter your example I want the contents of say A1 put into D1:D2 that are merged. So its a value of one cell going into two merged together

Comment: Having attempted to unmerge and try the procedure again, it is still pasting to cells outside of the area I would expect it to be in, so confused

Comment: Ok It will now paste into single cells but still not merged cells, will have a work on a function to check on whether the cells are merged and to make them single cells, paste the data and then re merge them

Comment: Do you need merged cells? I never use merged cells but instead use 'centre across selection' which is in Format Cells/Alignment/Horizontal/Centre across selection.

Comment: @ooo makes a good point, you may not need merged cells at all, which would be a very simple work-around for your problem.

Comment: The problem is that I am being given a workbook that is formatted by my boss, and each month it will open the previous workbook and use it to update to the new months workbook. Otherwise believe me with this hassle I would have left merged cells way on the horizon

Comment: Wow my answers make no sense at 8am, this should say that its an automated workbooks so I need it to be in vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I understand what you are saying then yes, but if I may alter your example I want the contents of say A1 put into D1:D2 that are merged. So its a value of one cell going into two merged together – JamesDev 4 hours ago

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set Rng1 = .Range("A1")
        Set Rng2 = .Range("D1:D2")

        '~~> Check if cells are merged
        If Rng2.MergeCells Then
            '~~> If merged then write to first cell
            Rng2.Cells(1, 1).Value = Rng1.Value
        Else
            Rng2.Value = Rng1.Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted....but it hasn't fixed the issue weirdly enough, it is still skipping the cells and placing to the right of the required destination. The cells all have dashes in them, I hadn't thought much of that before but on checking that means that they have the value 0 in them. I have tried deleting it out and seeing if it works but still nothing

Comment: Ok so taking out all of the formatting and deleting the values then allows for this to work so I will happily mark it as the correct answer. Is it simple to achieve looking at the range to see if there is a 0, deleting it and removing all formatting, copying the range and reapplying the formatting?